# Performance issue on lighting added

Tags: unreal-engine4

I added lighting to my game after I finished building the map.
99% of lighting is static point lights.
After I added those - my fps crashed from nice 40fps to 5fps.
I attach below the screenshot, I would appreciate your help how to optimize the performance such that I will be able to have at least 20fps.

[image]

I tried to turn off the "visible" in "Rendering" in all lights, but it didn't help at all. Still, I get the same 5fps.